# How to make a Popup save changes made inside of it?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I use Popups from Community Toolkit and I have a `Popup` page shown when a user presses a button. On that popup I have a `Picker`. When a user makes a choice and closes a popup their choice is passed back but if a user would later want to change the choice or look what they chose and call the popup again by pressing the button, a new clean popup will appear.
The question is: is it possible and if yes - how to make it so that on pressing the button the same instance of a popup is always shown with all the choices made before?

Popup page:

```
public partial class PopUpCreation : Popup
{   
    public PopUpCreation(ILocalizationResourceManager LocalizationResourceManager, Character player)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        //Some code

            Picker picker = new Picker();
            
            //Some Code       
                        
            picker.ItemsSource = scores;
            picker.SelectedIndexChanged += Picker_SelectedIndexChanged;
            Stack.Children.Add(picker);
    }

    private void Picker_SelectedIndexChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Some code
    }
}
```

Calling the popup:

```
private void ButtonAbilityScores_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    var result = this.ShowPopupAsync(new PopUpCreation(_LocalizationResourceManager, Player));
}
```

I don't really even have ideas how to do that and googling also didn't help me.

Thank you!

Comment: You're calling `new PopUpCreation()` everytime the Button is clicked. If you want to reuse the last one, just save declare a property/static/variable and initialize it once, then, reuse. It shouldn't really be a question.

Comment: @StephenQuan thanks.

I tried initializing the popup on the page it gets called from and pass it into a buttonclicked event handler. Now the first time I press it the popup is shown correctly, but the second time I get an exception:
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.Views.MauiPopup'.'

So as I understand it, once the popup is closed it gets disposed of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is : you can't. The goal of the Popup is to be created when needed, and disposed of once you don't need it anymore.

A workaround is not to save the Popup itself, but to save the infos you need for when you generate it :

```cs
public partial class PopUpCreation : Popup
{   
    public PopUpCreation(ILocalizationResourceManager LocalizationResourceManager, Character player, int SelectedIndexToRestore = -1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        //Some code

            Picker picker = new Picker();
            
            //Some Code       
                        
            picker.ItemsSource = scores;

            // Index -1 is used as default value for when you don't have a SelectedIndex to give
            if (SelectedIndexToRestore != -1) picker.SelectedIndex = SelectedIndexToRestore;

            picker.SelectedIndexChanged += Picker_SelectedIndexChanged;
            Stack.Children.Add(picker);
    }
}
```

You just have to save your SelectedIndexToRestore somewhere in your ViewModel or your AppData, so you can pass it to the popup constructor when calling it.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what i started to think after some time.

Answer (score 0):

I Have Two Idea For this:

1-you can Store You PopUp Or Page Controls such as picker,textbox,.. on the models that you can create

```
public class popupUpSetting
{
 public int PickerValue{get;set;}
}
```

then you can save it in database or other storage

or

2-you can define a static object from your popup then everytime you want show pass the static object

```
  static PopUpCreation popUpInstance;
```

then when want to show it like this:

```
   this.ShowPopupAsync(popUpInstance)
```

this way is not rational
the first idea is very common and have better performance if you want to persist your setting

Comment: Thank you.
It was my first thought just to store every change somewhere and restore them each time a new instance of the popup is called, but it just "feels" wrong. I guess if I wouldn't find another solution in a day or two, I'll do it like this.